# Prbolem in view when refreshing page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am retrieving a column from my database and storing that values in an array in my controller.
I am passing that array to the view page, and displaying that values to the user.
All things upto this are working fine.
But the problem is when I am refreshing the page its not showing the values obtained by the controller from the model and just showing blank page..\
I also tried to store the value in a session and use that value but that doesn't seem to work for me.. :(
here is my controller code :-

```
function full_post_view(){
            $data= array(
                'ticket_id' => $this->input->post('ticket_id')
            ); 
            $this->session->set_userdata($data); 
            $ticket_id = ($this->input->post('ticket_id')) ? $this->input->post('ticket_id') : $this->session->userdata('ticket_id');
//                $post_content = $this->session->userdata('post_content');
            echo $ticket_id;
            $this->load->model('helpdesk_model');
            $all_comments = $this->helpdesk_model->fetchComments($ticket_id);
            $is_post_closed = $this->helpdesk_model->fetchPostStatus($ticket_id);
            if($all_comments->num_rows > 0)  {
                foreach ($all_comments->result() as $comments_value) {
                    $comments = $comments_value->comments;
                }
                $count=1;
                Template::set('all_comments',$all_comments);
                Template::set_view('helpdesk/full_post_view');
            }
            else {
                $count=0;
                Template::set('post_content',$this->input->post('post_content'));
            }                 
            Template::set('is_post_close',$is_post_closed);
            Template::set('ticket_id',$ticket_id);
            Template::set('is_post_closed',$is_post_closed);
            Template::set('post_content',$post_content);
            Template::set('count',$count);                
            Template::set('is_post_closed',$is_post_closed);                
            Template::render();
    }
```

here is my view :-

```
<?php $post=Template::get('post_content'); ?>
<?php  $ticket_id=Template::get('ticket_id'); ?>
<?php  $is_close = Template::get('is_close'); ?>
<h4>Your Problem :- </h4>
<?php echo $post; ?>
<hr/>
<?php foreach ($is_post_closed->result() as  $value) {
    $is_close = $value->is_close;
} ?>
<?php if(Template::get('count') > 0) : ?>
    <?php foreach($all_comments->result_array() as $commentsRow) : ?>
        <?php echo word_wrap($commentsRow['comments'],15); ?>
    <?php echo " by->"; ?>
    <?php echo $commentsRow['username']; ?>
    <?php echo $commentsRow['role_name']; ?>
    <hr/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <br/>
    No Comments Yet
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($is_close == 0 ) : ?>
    <?php echo form_open('helpdesk/newComment'); ?>
    <?php echo form_hidden('ticket_id',$ticket_id); ?>
    <?php  echo form_hidden('post_content', $post); ?>
    <?php echo form_textarea('comment_from_user'); ?>
    <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Comment '); ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($is_close==0) : ?>
<?php echo form_open('helpdesk/closePost'); ?>
<?php echo form_hidden('ticket_id', $ticket_id); ?>
<?php  echo form_hidden('post_content', $post); ?>  
<?php echo form_submit('submit','close post'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php echo form_open('helpdesk/reopenPost'); ?>
<?php echo form_hidden('ticket_id', $ticket_id); ?>
<?php echo form_submit('submit','Reopen post'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Edit :**
I want to ask that how to load the database content again to the view when user refreshes the page.

Edited my Controller and view code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :)
the problem was when I was refreshing the page, ticket_id was set to 0 and that value was passed as a post . 
So the session value was the new ticket_id i.e., 0 and so it was displaying nothing..
I did this:-

```
if(isset($_POST['ticket_id'])) {
$data= array(
'ticket_id' => $this->input->post('ticket_id'),
                'post_content' => $this->input->post('post_content')
             ); 
             $this->session->set_userdata($data); 
}
        $ticket_id =$this->session->userdata('ticket_id');
        $post_content =$this->session->userdata('post_content');
```

i.e., I am storing ticket_id in session when post in set i.e., for the first time. When page is refreshed next time ticket_id post is not set and data is taken from session.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page, do you resend the form ? I'm asking this because from your controller code, it looks like `$ticket_id` is fetched from _POST and you use pass this variable to the model. If you don't resend the form, the `$ticket_id` is `null` and nothing is fetched from DB.

Edit:

Replace in your controller:

```
$ticket_id = $this->input->post('ticket_id');
```

with:

```
$ticket_id = ($this->input->post('ticket_id')) ? $this->input->post('ticket_id') : $this->session->userdata('ticket_id');
```

and make sure on each request `ticket_id` exists at least in one from the two possibilities (POST and SESSION)

Comment: yup that is the problem if I am resending the data the view page is fine but if I am not resending data, problem occurs...Its due to _POST of $ticket_id.
I am now storing ticket_id in session but that also not working
I have uploaded my latest controller and view code..please check it..

Comment: thanks for your answer.. this is working but the problem is when I am clicking to view contents with ticket_id=9 it is showing me  but on refreshing the page contents of ticket_id=6 is coming :(

Comment: not solved..:(
dont know what happened.. after logging out and logging again same problem is occuring... ticket id is not being passed :(]

Comment: on doing `echo $this->session->userdata('ticket_id');`
there is nothing result in the page

Comment: I have changed my controller and view code and ticket id is not being stored in session so on refreshing page this is not working.. is there any other method to carry datas from view to controller withour passing it to url i.e, without get or post..?

Comment: what I have to do is to store that ticket_id value so that each time when page is refreshed ticket_id value is fetched..can we use cache, I dont know how to use that..